# Get all Woocommerce products from current product category term Id in a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I have a simple taxonomy-product_cat.php page, where I am trying to display only the products in the current category. Right now, it's displaying all products, not just the ones in the current category. Here is my code:

```
<ul class="products">

    <?php
       $current_cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
       $args = array(
         'taxonomy'       => 'product_cat',
         'post_type'      => 'product',
         'post_status'    => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'tax_query'      => array(
             'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
             'field'      => 'term_id',
             'terms'      => $current_cat_id,
             'operator'   => 'IN'
         )
       );

       $products = new WP_Query( $args );

       while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
           echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'"><div class="product__preview"><img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . '"></div><span>' . get_the_title() . '</span></a></li>';
       endwhile;

       wp_reset_query();
       ?>
</ul>
```

My client keeps changing the names/slugs of the category, so I need to get the products by category ID. Any idea why this is generating all products, instead of just the ones in the current category?

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't seem to make a difference :(

Comment: I've removed `$wp-query->`, and the first `'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'`, but I'm still getting all products. Could it be a different snippet of code interfering somewhere else?

Comment: Still no luck. :\

Comment: I tried hard coding a nonsense number into the `'terms'` slot, and it's still showing all products, so it doesn't seem to be reading the terms at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2**

> The tax query need to have 2 arrays embedded in each other: `'tax_query' => array( array(`

Removed the first unneeded `'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',`

Replaced `'terms' => $current_cat_id,` by `'terms' => array( get_queried_object()->term_id ),`

Replaced wp_reset_query(); by `wp_reset_postdata();`

Your code will be:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
        'field'      => 'term_id',
        'terms'      => array( get_queried_object()->term_id ),
    ) )
) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'"><div class="product__preview"><img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . '"></div><span>' . get_the_title() . '</span></a></li>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Tested and works

Answer (score 3):

although its correct answer you can get it through category slug.

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'product_cat'    => 'category slug here',
    );
    $products_all = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**version tested 4.6.1**

Answer (score 0):

```
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );  
            $args_listing = array( 
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'tax_query'      => array( array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
            'field'      => 'term_id',
            'terms'      => $terms[0]->term_id,
            ) ),
            'orderby'=> 'date',
            'order'=> "desc",
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => $paged                   
            );


            I think you can try this. its working for me.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).